# In Swift, how do you retrieve the length of a UILabel?

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to determine how many characters are in a `UILabel` so I can call `numberOfLines` when necessary.

I remember in Obj-C, I was able to able to access `length` on a UILabel's `text` property like so:

```
if (self.label.text.length >= 12)
    // Do something
```

How can I achieve the same result in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myLabel = UILabel()
// ...
var numChars = myLabel.text?.characters.count ?? 0 // 0
myLabel.text = "Foo bar"
numChars = myLabel.text?.characters.count ?? 0     // 7
```

Comment: Does this return the actual "number" of characters in the UILabel string text?

Comment: @Pangu the `.text` property of an `UILabel` is just a string, so yes, the above returns the number of characters in your `UILabel`.

Comment: @Pangu: The question that Swift asks is: what do you mean by "length"? If you mean the number of composed character sequences, then yes, that's what this returns. If you mean the number of UTF-8 bytes, then there's a different way to compute that.

Comment: @jtbandes I think it's clear from the first sentence _"I am trying to determine how many characters are in a UILabel ..."_ that OP is referring to number of characters. However, the title could be more specific, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

based on @dfrib answer above,
here is the update for **Swift 5**

```
var myLabel = UILabel()
myLabel.text = "character"
let totalCharacter = myLabel.text?.count ?? 0

print("total character: \(totalCharacter)"
// total character: 9
```